# How can i submit form and move to the next page both at a time?

Tags: javascript, html

part of my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" id="form">

<input type="number" min="0" max="20" id="experience" required name="experience"title="experience" class="formfield" />

<input type="image" id="registersubmit4" name="registersubmit4" src="images/arrow-right.png"  title="next"/>

</form>
```

I want to submit form when user clicks on next and after submitting, then move to the next page.

```
<input type="image">
```

works well for submitting but after submitting i want to move to the next page..

I used javascript for onclick() event as follows:

```
<input type="image" onclick=form.submit(); "location='next.html'">
```

this does not work. Please help...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe give the redirecting task to the file you are submitting to.

Comment: See Diodeus's answer. So it is <form method="post" action="next.html" id="form">.......</form>

Comment: And please have quotes for the attribute values, such as  onclick="form.submit();"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually done by specifying an action on the form:

```
<form method="post" action="newpage.html" id="form">
```

...but if the page processing your form is different than the page you want to go to, you'd use a **server-side redirect**. How this works will depend on the server-side language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to solve my problem.

```
jQuery(window).attr("location", "your page or external link goes here");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). You could try doing something like this.

```
<script>
  // Attach a submit handler to the form
  $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
        exp = $form.find( "input[name='experience']" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post({
      url: url,
      data: { experience: exp } );
      success: function( data ) {
        window.location='next.html';
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to include an entire library just to do something as simple as submit a form.  Especially whenever native HTML does it stock, and without JavaScript.